# How do I cause or prevent Interference, Interceptions, Deadlocks etc.?

Tags: the-last-remnant

During battles, I feel like I have no idea what's going on.  My unit-groups will intercept and be intercepted; interfere and be interfered (?); flank and be flanked; and become deadlocked *(is this even a bad thing?)*.  This all happens seemingly at random.

Is there any way of knowing which actions will flank or interfere (etc.) another unit-group?  Or of knowing when they'll do it to me?  Can I prevent it?  Do I even *want* to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different occurrences during a battle in The Last Remnant, and its not easy for a beginner to understand exactly what causes them.

**Deadlocks**

When two unions engage each other in close combat, a **Deadlock** is triggered. It basically means just that: the unions are fighting in close range. It doesn't carry any bonuses or disadvantages to be Deadlocked. However, when the combat situation changes, unions can be subject to different types of Deadlocks and Flank Attacks.

**Multi Deadlock**

There are some special unions in the game which have the ability to Deadlock multiple unions at once. This occurrence is known as a **Multi Deadlock**.

**Raidlock**

A **Raidlock** is a special kind of deadlock which can happen in a couple of different situations. It's more or less a kind of surprise attack which does more damage.

The following situations can trigger a Raidlock:

1. When a union cancels a Deadlock, for example to heal, being Deadlocked again by the union which it was previously deadlocking will result in a Raidlock.
2. If a union is on standby, being Deadlocked by another union will also result in a Raidlock.
3. Similarly, Deadlocking a union which had just executed a long range attack will cause it to become Raidlocked.
4. Finally, if a Rear Assault or Flank Attack command is issued to a union but no friendly unions are deadlocking the target of the command, a Raidlock is initiated instead.

The advantages of a Raidlock is that the attacking union deals extra damage.

**Interference and Interception**

When engaging an enemy union which is on the way to Deadlock one of your other unions, you can force it into a Deadlock with your engaging union instead. This is known as **Interference**. Similarly, when the enemy does the same to you, it is called **Interception**.

**Flank Attack**

When a union is Deadlocked, being attacked from the sides in melee range is known as a **Flank Attack**. It results in a bonus to the damage dealt to that union. A union can be flanked by two other unions at one time.

**Rear Assault**

Unions flanked by two enemy unions will be subject to a **Rear Assault** if it is Deadlocked by another enemy union, which carries an even larger bonus to the damage received than being Flanked Attacked does.

**Massive Strike**

When a union is currently in a state of being Rear Assaulted, being flanked by an additional union will result in a **Massive Strike**, which further increases the damage bonus.

**Reinforcements**

Sometimes, additional unions can enter a battle already in progress. This is known as the side receiving the reinforcements being **Reinforced**. It increases the morale of the reinforced side.

**How do I cause or prevent these situations?**

Essentially, it comes down to knowing the state of the battlefield. Failing to engage some enemy unions in Deadlocks can leave your Deadlocked unions open to being flanked by them. However, you can also apply this in order to flank enemy unions. Having the advantage of numbers will make it easier to achieve flanks.

It's not as easy as it sounds though, since there is no way to get a quick, graphical overview of the current situation. You just have to picture it for yourself.

Source:
[The Last Remnant Wiki](http://lastremnant.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_Basics)